# Have any well-known results been refuted by a theorem prover?

Tags: automated-theorem-proving, proof-assistants

Have any well-known results in mathematics or computer science been shown to be *false* through the use of a theorem prover or proof assistant? I am not interested in cases where the *proof* of a *true* result was shown to be flawed and that the theorem prover provided a correct proof. I mean specifically that the negative of a published (and ideally cited) result was shown or checked by machine.

Comment: I don't know if enough "advanced" stuff has been proved in CS, but you can find a similar question and relevant answers for mathematics [here on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291158/proofs-shown-to-be-wrong-after-formalization-with-proof-assistant).